# How to change directory in own root server for access via NetworkCredential(Username, Password)

Tags: c#, .htaccess, networkcredentials

I got error 401, unautherized access

Error-message from Webclient:

> The remote server has returned an error: (401) not authorized.

if I want to access to a directory via c# webclient class.
Problem: Authorisation to the directory faild, connection works, list of files in directory was also already shown.

I already saved the directory at the browser interface of my provider. 
I also tested .htaccess to secure this directory with username and password, no success.

Maybe I did something wrong, but the code has to be fine because if I add 
Options +Indexes 
solely to the .htaccess I already mentioned to get a list of files in this directory. But if I want to download these files the error above occurs (401 unauthorized access).

Do you have any ideas how I could change access to my directory using an username and password to download files from this directory via C# webclient?

My Code:

```
Client.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
Client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("user", "pw");

Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location) + Path.DirectorySeparatorChar + "DownloadArchive");

        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("url/directory");
        using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
        {
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                string html = reader.ReadToEnd();
                Regex regex = new Regex(GetDirectoryListingRegexForUrl("url/directory"));
                MatchCollection matches = regex.Matches(html);
                if (matches.Count > 0)
                {
                    foreach (Match match in matches)
                    {
                        if (match.Success)
                        {
                            Client.DownloadFile("url/directory" + match.Groups["name"], 
Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location) + @"\" + "DownloadArchive" + Path.DirectorySeparatorChar + 
match.Groups["name"]);
                            writer.Log("File " + match.Groups["name"] + " downloaded into " + 
Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location) + Path.DirectorySeparatorChar + "DownloadArchive");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

.htaccess, which worked to read all filenames in directory:

```
Options +Indexes
```

.htaccess, which I tried adding a username and password:

```
AuthType Basic
AuthUserFile /root/.passwd
AuthName "HTACCESS TEST"
order deny,allow
allow from all
require valid-user
```

.passwd in directory root, was created with htpasswd program via putty on root server:

```
UserName:{SHA}...........................
```

Comment: Putting an error message in German is basically as useful as not posting the error message at all, since this is an *English* community.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto I translated it :)

Comment: Well I just put it as it was... and if you had read further you would have seen the translation.